# Recursive, generic type - deep type check

Tags: generics, typescript, recursion, types

I would like to create recursive, generic type `TRecursive` based on my data interfaces `IOne`, `ITwo` and `IThree` that are related as shown below.

The result type `TRecursive<IOne>` should have similar relations as `IOne` but different value types, e.g. `boolean` in example below.

```
interface IOne {
    pk: number;
    name: string;
    two: ITwo;
}

interface ITwo {
    pk: number;
    name: string;
    three: IThree;
}

interface IThree {
    pk: number;
    name: string;
}

type TRecursive<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: TRecursive<T[P]> | boolean;
};

const test: TRecursive<IOne> = {
    pk: true,
    name: true,
    two: {
        pk: true,
        name: true,
        anything: true,        // type error as expected
        three: {
            pk: true,
            name: true,
            anything: true     // no error - why?
        }
    }
};
```

The thing is I cannot make `typescript@2.3.3` to work properly when I need type-check down in related types.

I added key `anything` that is not defined in my data types, so I would like typescript to show me the error here. As expected I see error in one level deep (inside key `two`), but the same key does not trigger error two levels deep (inside key `three`).

Why is that? Is there anything that I can do to achieve this with typescript?

Comment: The only explanation for this that I can think of is it's a compiler bug. Open an issue in the TS GitHub repo, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common with TS. It stops at the first error before even continuing to look for the next ones.

```
const test: TRecursive<IOne> = {
    pk  : true,
    name: true,
    two : {
        pk   : true,
        name : true,
        // anything: true,
        three: {
            pk      : true,
            name    : true,
            anything: true, // error
        },
    },
}
```